# Fabric.js is not showing on IE 11

Tags: javascript

I've got very frustrating bug here. 
Finishing my site now and testing it on all browsers.
I've found, that it works fine on Firefox, Chrome and Safari.
But it won't work on IE.

Just empty space where canvas should be and no errors fired in console.

Would someone give me a clue on this?

```html
//Групповое выделение объектов таблицы
fabric.Canvas.prototype.multipleSelection = function(selectionMode = "column") {
main.js:3205SyntaxError: Expected token ')'

    objects = this.getObjects();

    for (var i = 0, len = Objects.length; i < len; i++) {

        if (selectionMode == "column") {
            if (Objects[i].columnNum==num && Objects[i].columnNum!=0){
                this.setActiveObject(Objects[i]); 
            }

        } else if (selectionMode == "row") {
            if (Objects[i].rowNum==num && Objects[i].myType=="captionBorder"){
                this.setActiveObject(Objects[i]); 
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
};
```

Here is the link http://motivashka-board.ru/konstruktor.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, to prevent your account getting a  negative score and possibly a question ban, next time post example code what produces the error. The error needs to be reproducable on here by others. Also keep stuff like thanks out of your question.
In your answers produce a working solution that also benefits others. You could consider self deleting this question because it's no benefit to others, or rewrite it, so it can gather upvotes so the downvotes won't negatively affect your total score. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a problem myself. 
I've installed Safari for windows and it showed me the error in Debug mode.
I wonder, why IE won't show it.
The problem was in a missing bracket.

Comment: Better to delete the question instead.